# JWT refresh token overview

Tags: token, jwt, access-token

I hope someone can help me here. I'm trying to understand token authentication, having read few tutorials regarding JWT tokens. I feel I've got the basic understanding though need bit more clarification regarding using refresh token:

- General behaviour is to set access token with shorter TTL and refresh token a bit longer, what I'm keen to understand is if the application being built is video playback, and if refresh token is set to expire at 2 hours and the video is 3 hours long, what is the expected behaviour ?
- Would the application be expected to renew the refresh token in the background and not cause any user interruption ?
- Or would this cause user interruption (I don't think this is correct)
- Is the refresh token always time based (e.g., set to 2 hours or 6 hours, etc), can it be event based ? So if the user selects video playback, it is set to expire once the video is finished ?

Thanks

Comment: I'd say the expiration time is usually set to automatically log the user out after some time of inactivity. So how about making the client automatically request a new token when the old one is close to expire, during video playback or whenever useractivity is detected.

Comment: And nothing would keep you from requesting a new token with a longer expiration time when video playback is detected, but you can't really know how many seconds of the video the user will end up watching.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to clarify, this would imply event based triggering of refresh token (obviously still within the overall expiration window). I wasn't sure if this was possible. So the client would have to detect playback and then send refresh token

Comment: Yes, this should work without any problems.